# wmic memorychip get Capacity | findstr [0-9] show different behavior when outside of FOR cycle and when in FOR cycle

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

For example, this code works fine

```
wmic MEMORYCHIP get Capacity | findstr [0-9] >> D:\ram-cpu.txt
```

And give memory banks capacity as output

But if I put this command in cycle

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@SET /a sl_counter=0
@FOR /F "usebackq" %%a IN (`wmic MEMORYCHIP get Capacity | findstr [0-9]`) DO (
@ECHO SLOT !sl_counter! %%a >> D:\ram-cpu.txt
@SET /a sl_counter=sl_counter+1
)
```

I recieve error

```
Unexpected: |.
D:\>@FOR /F "usebackq" %a IN (`wmic MEMORYCHIP get Capacity | findstr [0-9]`) DO
 (
```

I guess I need some syntax to be added or fixed, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape `|` by `^|` when you use it inside the `for` command

***Commandline*** :

```
@FOR /F "usebackq" %a IN (`wmic MEMORYCHIP get Capacity ^| findstr [0-9]`) DO echo %a
```

***Batch File :***

```
@echo off
@FOR /F "usebackq" %%a IN (`wmic MEMORYCHIP get Capacity ^| findstr [0-9]`) DO Set "Memory=%%a"
    echo %Memory%
pause
```

---

Further Reading about : [How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)